# Do the ubuntu core/snappy images have checksums/hashes?

Tags: ubuntu-core

It's not at all clear from [the site](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/). How are you supposed to reason about security if the base OS images aren't authenticated?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Each version and derivation of Ubuntu has checksums.

Please see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

## Ubuntu Core Example

1. Go to the link above.
2. Select the link next to `ubuntu-core`.

   > [image: Ubuntu Version]
3. Select the version you want. In this example, we'll pick `16.04`.

   > [image: Versions]
4. Select the branch you want. There's only one listed, so we'll pick `beta-2`.

   > [image: Branch]
5. The next page shows all the files relevant to that version and branch. The `*SUMS` files contains the checksums. The `*gpg` files are the detached GPG signature relevant to each checksum file respectively.

   > [image: Downloads]

### Verification

Based on the example above, here is the `SHA256SUM` file.

```
4c78cc17b21d47f5b808556d1485bab783e1e080b1d587517819dddf0e8b53f0 *ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-amd64.tar.gz
c8c8733f235d734550326d7584e3eccfbc9bb5ff0f15341fa89962f7589494be *ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-arm64.tar.gz
46d047b59bb71af61e31f4d5fe90d271d9dca1a0ee6b31fd4a5a67c3de793780 *ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-armhf.tar.gz
b16853573b8d83d570511899bddae9b468bdf86532603a6de6881911663f13e7 *ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-i386.tar.gz
1712246003dc1b46ab25143cf0d476a95a76467c052da2b11d119238d0c1dc43 *ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-powerpc.tar.gz
1c46e0582648bfe221322cae88a4420820c163c07660b2e53719ae0ec966a93d *ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-ppc64el.tar.gz
```

Each file on the right has their checksum on the left.

What follows is me verifying the integrity of the files via the `sha256sum` command.

```
norman@laptop:~/Downloads$ ls
SHA256SUMS.txt
ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-amd64.tar.gz
ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-arm64.tar.gz
ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-armhf.tar.gz
ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-i386.tar.gz
ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-powerpc.tar.gz
ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-ppc64el.tar.gz
norman@laptop:~/Downloads$ sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS.txt 
ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-amd64.tar.gz: OK
ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-arm64.tar.gz: OK
ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-armhf.tar.gz: OK
ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-i386.tar.gz: OK
ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-powerpc.tar.gz: OK
ubuntu-core-16.04-beta2-core-ppc64el.tar.gz: OK
norman@laptop:~/Downloads$
```

## Conclusion

You can apply this method to any of the other Ubuntu versions / branches.

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.

And have a great day!

Comment: I'm confused. The snappy site provides disk images, which is what I'd like. The site you linked to has tarballs, I guess of rootfses? Are there hashes for the images?

Comment: Ah! I understand now.

They're a bit hard to find, but I've found them. For example [this](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-snappy/15.04/stable/latest/) is for Rasberry Pi.